# href to a page + change class name by .js at once

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with some links like this:
**test1.html**

```
<div>
<a href="test2.html">Go to TAB1</a>
<a href="test2.html">Go to TAB2</a>
</div>
```

The second page is a page with tabs:
**test2.html**

```
<div id="tab1" class="active-content">      
     <p>Hello this is the first TAB</p>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="content">
    <p>Hello this is the second TAB</p>
</div>
```

What I need to do, is that when I click on `Go to TAB2` href, change to page `test2.html` and also change the div class so they look like this: (In order to show the second TAB when the page loads).

```
<div id="tab1" class="content">      
     <p>Hello this is the first TAB</p>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="active-content">
    <p>Hello this is the second TAB</p>
</div>
```

I tried using javascript `href="javascript:tab()"` but I cant do the two things at once. The page changes to `test2.html` but runs the code before the page is load.

```
function tab(){
    window.location.href='test2.html';
    var element = document.getElementById("tab1");
    element.className="content";
    var element = document.getElementById("tab2");
    element.className="active-content";
}
```

I tried using `setTimeout` or `onload` method but nothing.
I need to change to test2.html and also change to the second TAB just clicking in an href, how can I do this?

Comment: Try using URL like `test2.html#tab1`, and have your `onload` method check `document.location.hash`.

Comment: I tried using `test2.html#tab2` but goes to the #tab1, which is the deault one. I cant put the `onload to #tab2` because I also want to appear the tab1 with the first link

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to send some data using the URL. This would be picked up by the test2 page, and can be acted upon.

A reference to an anchor on another page is defined by a hash:

```
test2.html#tab1
```

This would ordinarily scroll the page to the anchor, but you can write a small javascript to parse the URL for a "#" and change the relevant class:

```
var url_raw=window.location.href;

//Split the string at the #, and take the second part
var layer_to_change=url.split("#")[1];

//Set the class of the needed layer
document.getElementById(layer_to_change).className="active-content";
```

This would reside in the onload event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Add a fragment:

```
<a href="test2.html#tab2">Go to TAB2</a>
```

Then on test2.html have this JavaScript:

```
var tabnum = location.hash.replace('#', '');
if (tabnum) {
    document.getElementById(tabnum).className = "active-content";
}
```